# How to find the norm of an imaginary exponential expresion?

Tags: complex

I need to find the norm of the following expression

$$
|1+e^{-i2\pi w}+e^{-i4\pi w}|^2$$

With w real number.

For doing this I coded:

```
a = 1 + Exp[-2*Pi* I w] + 0.5 Exp[-4 Pi w I]
Norm[a]^2
```

The output is:

```
Norm[1 + E^(-2 I \[Pi] w) + 0.5 E^(-4 I \[Pi] w)]^2
```

So the code is not calculating effectively the norm.

Comment: `Abs[a]` or `Norm[{a}]`.  `Norm` is for vectors only.  — In addition, you might need to apply `Simplify` (and/or `ComplexExpand` if `w` is real).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes w is real. But using simplify is not working very well.

Comment: Maybe `Simplify[ComplexExpand@Abs[a], w \[Element] Reals]`?  It might work better if the half in `a` were the exact `Rational` number `1/2` instead of the approximate `Real` (floating-point) `0.5`.

Comment: `In[218]:= a = 1 + Exp[-2*Pi*I w] + 1/2 Exp[-4 Pi w I]; ComplexExpand[
 a*Conjugate[a]]

Out[218]= 1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Pi] w] + Cos[2 \[Pi] w]^2 + Cos[4 \[Pi] w] + 
 Cos[2 \[Pi] w] Cos[4 \[Pi] w] + 1/4 Cos[4 \[Pi] w]^2 + 
 Sin[2 \[Pi] w]^2 + Sin[2 \[Pi] w] Sin[4 \[Pi] w] + 
 1/4 Sin[4 \[Pi] w]^2` and then simplify if so desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 1 + Exp[-2*Pi* I w] + 0.5 Exp[-4 Pi w I];
Rationalize[ComplexExpand@Abs[a] // FullSimplify]^2
```

$ 3 \cos (2 \pi  w)+\cos (4 \pi  w)+\frac{9}{4}$